# set state in a callback of an async function

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React, so bear with me please. I have a component that calls another component that takes a property. This property will get it's value on a callback of a function, something like this:

```
render(){
  myFunc((p) => {
    if(!_.isEqual(p, this.state.myProp))
      this.setState({myProp: p})
  });
  return <MyComponent myProp={this.state.myProp}/> 
}
```

`myFunc` will or will not make an API request and depending on that will call the callback sooner or later. This seems to work fine when API request is made and the callback takes longer to return. However, when the request is not needed and callback returns instantaneously (or almost) I am getting a `` Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state. `` 
What am I doing wrong and what is the right way to approach this? Where would be the right place to put this code? Basically what I need is to re-render MyComponenent if this.state.myProp changes

Comment: Do not call `setState` from `render`. Use `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate` and/or event handlers for such things.

Comment: neither one would work (I tried). ComponentDidUpdate happens after render and componentDidMount happens only once and I need to re-render multiple times depending on user actions

Comment: what is the context in which `p` is not equal to `this.state.myProp`? Where does `p` come from? Also the posted code is not valid, there is at least one missing close parenthesis.

Comment: the callback is called with ```p```

Comment: @chibis right, but what gets passed into the callback as `p`?

Comment: ```myFunc = function(callback: (obj) => void){ var obj={}; /*make API call and set obj to result*/ callback(obj) }``` ```obj``` would be something that ```myProp``` needs to be set to

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be calling `setState` inside the `render` method, you might end up having an infinite loop.
The call to `myFunc` should be somewhere else (depending on the business logic you have). When the function finishes, it will update the state and then trigger a re-render so `MyComponent` will get the latest value.

**UPDATE**

I don't know which conditions will require calling myFunc again, but you can do:

```
state = {
  myProp: null // or some other value that MyComponent can handle as a null state
}

componentDidMount () {
  myFunc((p) => {
    if(!_.isEqual(p, this.state.myProp)) // This is needed only if you get null back from the callback and you don't want to perform an unnecesary state update
      this.setState({myProp: p})
  }
}

render(){
  const { myProp } = this.state
  // You can also do if (!myProp) return null  
  return <MyComponent myProp={myProp}/> 
}
```

Comment: that is exactly my question, where should I call myFunc from. Render seems the only good place, but as I said I am new to React, so I don't know. The purpose of myFunc is to generate a value for the property that is passed to myComponent

Comment: Do you need to update the data? under what conditions you should be calling `myFunc` again?

Comment: ```myFunc``` is always called on render. It takes a callback which is called with a value that is used to set ```this.state.myProp``` if it is different from its current value

Comment: If you don't have any other condition, for example: "if this other field changes then I need to go and call `myFunc` again because it might return different data", then my update should work.

Comment: yes, this is exactly what happens. There is another filed/property that changes which causes the re-render and hence myFunc needs to be called again, so ```componentDidMount``` doesn't work for me

Comment: Yes, you will have the same problems if you use a lifecycle method. Remember those are triggered when the component is updated and since you are calling `setState`, it will trigger again ending up on an infinite loop.
I need more info about the conditions that will make `myFunc` return different data in order to give you a better answer.

Comment: I have ```this.state.p1``` and ```this.state.p2```. When ```this.state.p1``` changes ```myFunc``` needs to be called. It would generate an ```object``` and call the callback with it. In the callback I need to re-render ```myComponent``` with new value for ```myProp```: ```<MyComponenet myProp={this.state.p2}/>```

Comment: Sounds like the best place is along with the setState of p1. `myFunc(...callbackHere); this.setState({ p1 })`

Comment: this did get rid of the error and seems to do the trick after a few tweaks. Still learning why things work the way they do and really appreciate your help on this

Comment: Yes, it might be tricky at the beginning. You should avoid calling `setState` in the updating methods, even though you can do it conditionally, but it might end up causing unnecessary re-renders or the worst case, infinite loop. I highly recommend taking a look at the documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle).